# How to remove a container prepended to the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a container and prepended it to the body:

```
// Create container
var container = "<div class='foo'> ... </div>";

// Prepend it to the body
$("body").prepend(container);
```

Now I want to fade out the container after several seconds:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    container.fadeOut();
}, 3000);
```

However, it says that undefined is not a function. I am quite sure `$(".foo").fadeOut()` will work, but I have quite a few of those `.foo` containers and I don't want to assign a separate id to each of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make your `container` var point to a jq object instead of a string:

```
var container = $('<div class="foo"> ... </div>');

// Prepend it to the body
$("body").prepend(container);

setTimeout(function() {
   container.fadeOut();
}, 3000);
```

now, `container`  has a `fadeOut()` method instead of being a dumb string.

EDIT: per request, a vanilla version of the creation part:

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.className="foo";
container.innerHTML= "<b>Hello world</b>";
document.body.insertBefore(container, document.body.firstChild);
```

the fadeOut part in vanilla:

```
<style> 
        div.foo{ opacity: 1; transition: 1000ms opacity;}
        div.foo.fade { opacity: 0; }
</style>

  setTimeout(function(){ container.classList.add("fade");}, 3000);
```

Comment: This one actually worked. Can you tell me what $('<div class="foo"> ... </div>'); would look like in pure JS (just in case)?

Comment: I would expect an error `container.fadeOut is not a function.` wondering why he is getting `undefined` when `container` is a `string`

Comment: @sabithpocker: not a bad point but i assumed the error report was non-verbatum and it just didn't work...

Comment: @sabithpocker, my bad. It said undefined is not a function.

Comment: @dandavis, Thanks for the pure JS version. It actually makes more sense for me.

Answer (score 2):

It should be this way:

```
var container = $("<div class=`foo`><h1>Hello World</h1></div>")
$("body").prepend(container);
setTimeout(function() {
    container.fadeOut();
}, 3000);
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/aLn378mk/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var container = $("<div class='foo'><h1>Something...</h1></div>")
   $("body").prepend(container);
   setTimeout(function() {
   container.fadeOut();
   }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to your 'container' variable. The fadeOut functionality would work on DOM Objects only. Not strings. Convert the string to a DOM object using:

```
var container = $('Your Code Here');
```

Answer (score -1):

`container` is string var. The DOM element indicated by container string can be accessed like `$('div.foo')`. So your `fadeout` call will change like->

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('div.foo').fadeOut();
}, 3000);
```